# C# type casting to a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a library that renders a bunch of *child* objects to screen. The child object is abstract, and it is intended for users of this library to derive their own child from this abstract class.

```
public abstract class Child : IRenderable {}

public interface IParent<T> where T : Child
{
   IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}
```

The complication is that I do not have a list of IParent to work with, instead, I have a bunch of IRenderables. The user of the library is expected to write something like this:

```
public class Car : IRenderable { }
public class Cow : IRenderable, IParent<Calf> { }
public class Calf : Child { }

// note this is just an example to get the idea
public static class App
{
   public static void main()
   {
      MyLibraryNameSpace.App app = new MyLibraryNameSpace.App();
      app.AddRenderable(new Car()); // app holds a list of IRenderables
      app.AddRenderable(new Cow());
      app.Draw(); // app draws the IRenderables
   }
}
```

In Draw(), the library *should* cast and check whether the IRenderable is also an IParent. However, since I do not know about the Calf, I don't know what to cast Cow into.

```
// In Draw()
foreach(var renderable in Renderables)
{
   if((parent = renderable as IParent<???>) != null) // what to do?
   {
      foreach(var child in parent.Children)
      {
          // do something to child here.
      }
   }
}
```

How can I overcome this problem? Is this anything to do with covariance generics or what-so-ever (I am not familiar with the covariance concept)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `IParent<T>` only *returns* items of type `T`, you could make it covariant using the [`out` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx):

```
public interface IParent<out T> where T : Child
{
   IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}
```

This would make `IParent<anything>` convertible to `IParent<Child>`:

```
IParent<Child> parent = renderable as IParent<Child>; // works for Cow
```

---

Note that covariance only works as long as you are only *returning* objects of type `T` (simply speaking). For example, as soon as you add an `AddChild(T)` method to your `IParent` interface, covariance must break (= the compiler will complain), since, otherwise, the following type-unsafe code could be written:

```
IParent<Child> parent = renderable as IParent<Child>;
parent.AddChild(new Kitten()); // can't work if parent is really a Cow.
```

Comment: `IParent<object>` is not legal (it won't satisfy the `T : Child` condition), and it doesn't really make it a *superclass* - rather, it allows the compiler and runtime to make use of variance.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks, fixed. Overlooked the constraint.

Comment: Appreciate the extra explanation in the edits. Really helped alot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement intermediate non-generic interface IParent:

```
public interface IParent
{
    IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; }
}

public interface IParent<T> : IParent
  where T: Child
{
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}
```

And then cast to IParent in your function.

Comment: Before C# 4.0 this was our limit, but from c# 4.0 onwards, the variance approach outlined in Heinzi's answer is typically preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the following lines?

```
static void draw(List<IRenderable> renderables)
{
    foreach (IRenderable render in renderables)
    {
        if (render is IParent<Child>)
        {
            foreach (Child c in ((IParent<Child>)render).Children)
            {
                //do something with C?
            }
        } 
    }
}
```